Action as the complex phase of the wave function of quantum mechanics
I heard that the action of classical mechanics can be seen as the complex phase of the wave function of quantum mechanics
$$\psi=\rho \exp\left(\frac{iS}{\hbar}\right)\tag1$$
I am more familiar with the stationary state wavefunction of the form
$${\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf {r} ,t)=\psi (\mathbf {r} )e^{-i{Et/\hbar }}}\tag2$$
Equation $(1)$ seems really nice in that it connects classical mechanics (action) to quantum mechancis (wavefunction), but I can not wrap my head around it. I can not find any derivation of it or any physical meaning.
I found only that when we input $(1)$ into the Schrödinger equation and take the classical limit we obtain the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.
What is the physical interpretation of equation $(1)$ and how did we obtain it?

In connecting classical and quantum mechanics, typically the only thing we can ask for is that in the classical limit (which is often formally taken as the limit $\hbar\rightarrow 0$), the predictions of quantum mechanics match the predictions of classical mechanics.
The phase of the wavefunction is not the classical action in general; a general state will be a complicated superposition of many classical paths, for example. However, in the classical limit, if we write $\psi=\rho e^{i S/\hbar}$ and take the $\hbar\rightarrow 0$ limit, we find that the variable $S$ obeys the same equation that the classical action does in the Hamilton-Jacobi equation, as you've seen. This is the connection. This is one manifestation of the WKB approximation.
Historically, this result was very interesting and important, because it connected with Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization, which was a pre-quantum model that allowed one to calculate fine-structure of Hydrogen.

I am having trouble grasping the notion $\hbar\rightarrow 0$. What does it actually mean? Does it mean the limit as reduced Plancks constant goes to zero? But it already is a really small quantity, its not that big of a change when it goes to zero. Or does it mean something different?

It means you take formulas where Planck's constant appears, ignore its numerical value, and formally take the limit $\hbar\rightarrow 0$. Of course $\hbar$ is small, which is why the classical world exists at all, but I disagree that it doesn't make a big change; for example if you take $\hbar\rightarrow 0$ in the Planck distribution for thermal radiation, you get the ultraviolet catastrophe!

Ah right! You are right, it does make a big change. Thanks

OP's eq. (1) is the WKB Ansatz for the wavefunction $\psi$ in the TDSE, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post. Here $S$ is Hamilton's principal function; not the action per se.
